# How to estimate the local trend in a signal?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, filtering, time-series

I need to remove trend from my time-series which looks like the following images.

However, I want to estimate the trend before removing it. Hence directly removing it won't do it.

The simple polynomial models didn't work, because — I think — the signal is long and the trend is changing. Also, filtering the signal with low pass removed too much of the trend as well.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

The files are available [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhwTPgIPfVcLdqC4HtLvJIZNRcU?e=SNH6Mj).

Comment: high-pass filter?  or compute sliding median and subtract that from the data?

Comment: Which simple polynomial models?  References, please

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, highpass? it is a low frequency phenomenon, no?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, i used matlab `detrend` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html.

Comment: "trend" and "local" are contradictory terms. Which trend exactly do you want to remove ? (Please a more descriptive answer than "the one on the plot".)

Comment: "filtering", do you mean using *the* filter ?

Comment: Yes, @Thomas , the trend baseline **is** a low-frequency phenomenon and one way to get rid of some low-frequency thing is to highpass filter.

Comment: @PeterK., the link is to a case of removing the trend. i'm after estimating it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, i think i'm after estimating it.

Comment: @PeterK., i wrote about the estimation of the trend.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/how-to-remove-or-filter-the-drift-problem-in-measured-strain-signal

Comment: Well, @Thomas ,  I wonder what a sliding median filter output would look like on your signal.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, it works well on some segments but fails too often.

Comment: how long is the window of your sliding median?  did you try different lengths?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I did. It is not stable. Unless I have a method to optimize the window size given the signal.

Comment: I cannot see how a sliding median filter is unstable.  If the data going in is bounded the output of the sliding median will be bounded with no worse than the same bounds.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I meant the results it gives are not limited to the trend. It is very sensitive to the choice of the window length. See the answer by Peter K.

Comment: @Thomas, Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 5):

Start simple: just use a 1-D median filter of an appropriate length.

If I do that with a length of 100 samples, I get the following for your first signal.

[image: Signal, and median filtered signal.]

The top plot shows the original signal (blue) and the median filtered signal (red).  The bottom plot shows just the zoomed-in median filtered signal.

Another possibility is to use a [DC Blocker.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/how-to-remove-or-filter-the-drift-problem-in-measured-strain-signal)

---

### Code Below

```
load signals_samples.mat
clf

for k=1:10

    figure(k)
    clf
    subplot(211)
    plot(signals_samples{k})
    hold on
    plot(medfilt1(signals_samples{k},100),'r')
    subplot(212)
    plot(medfilt1(signals_samples{k},100))

end
```

Comment: Any chance you add the link in your answer?

Comment: @Thomas D'oh! I see what you mean now. Thanks for the clarification.  Done.

Answer (score 3):

In [A Self Supervised Learning for a Signal Denoising](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84570) I wrote:

> You may have a look at the method called [JOT: A Variational Signal Decomposition Into Jump, Oscillation and Trend](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9693096) (You may access it in [A Two Stage Signal Decomposition into Jump, Oscillation and Trend Using ADMM](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2023/417/)).
>
> This method basically does what you're after, it decomposes the signal into 3 signals:
>
> [image]
>
> You may look on the results of a signal similar to yours:
>
> [image]
>
> The method is quite simple if you know ADMM.
> In any way, they supply code.

You signals looks very long, so it might stress the solver for memory.
Still worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the JOT method suggested by @Royi, the [BEADS algorithm](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/siva-beads-baseline-background-removal-filtering-sparsity.html) decomposes a signal in three components:

- a trend,
- a sparse signal,
- a residual (which can be used as quality control).

I did a quick test on your first signal. BEADS is not (yet) good at the beginning and end, but it is quite fast: 0.25 seconds for the first signal. It scales almost linearly with signal size. Its parameters allow to control the smoothness of the trend. Here are the results. Parameters follow.

[image: BEADS trend removal]

```
data1 = [signals_samples{1}];
% Filter parameters
fc = 0.0035;     % fc : cut-off frequency (cycles/sample)
d = 1;          % d : filter order parameter (d = 1 or 2)

% Positivity bias (peaks are positive)
r = 1;          % r : asymmetry parameter

% Regularization parameters
% amp = 0.8;      
amp = 0.1;      
lam0 = 1*amp;
lam1 = 5*amp;
lam2 = 2*amp;
 [data1Filt, dataBaseline, cost] = beads(data1, d, fc, r, lam0, lam1, lam2);
```

Comment: What can be done to improve this?

Comment: I am not sure of what you need to improve here. There are many options. The simplest is to perform a preprocessing such that both ends are tapper to zero